# Why do I sometimes get one more flag to use in the middle of the day?

Tags: discussion, bug, flag-weight

Over the last few days, I have used up my entire supply of flags each day. After doing so, I see that I have 0 flags remaining. However, on some days, I see that I have one flag remaining *several hours after seeing that I had 0 flags remaining.* Is this a bug or a product of how the number of available flags is counted?

I normally use up my entire supply of flags within a 5-10 minute period, so it doesn't seem like the 24-hour period is rolling over and giving me more flags. When the 24-hour period does change (UTC time, correct?) I get my full supply of flags back.

More data from my profile, if it helps.

```
422 moderator attention flags
418 deemed helpful
2   declined
2   disputed

2   comments flagged
2   deemed helpful
```

Comment: Maybe you regain flags for questions that get deleted? Just speculation though, I don't know for sure

Comment: Is it possible that you got enough flags marked helpful that you were given an extra flag for good flagging?

Comment: @Pekka That sounds plausible. Can anyone else verify that?

Comment: Since you're not yet getting extra flags for passing the next 2k rep multiple, I think it's what Flexo said, your flag-weight passes the next one-more-flag limit.

Comment: Looking at your stats, I'm pretty sure it's the good-flagging bonus.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wouldn't that happen at the 24-hour mark, though? I do notice that one day I can flag 39 questions, then 40 the next day, etc.

Comment: I'm not quite sure (that's why it's a comment and not an answer), but I noticed the increase from passing the 2k multiple take effect immediately. So why wouldn't the flag-weight increase also?